# Minlength validation not firing when text field has value set

Tags: html, forms, validation

The following code validates minlength fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="result.html">
    <input type="text" required minlength="4" name="textfield"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

If I type `ab` in the field, it will generate a minlength error. However, if I add a value attribute to the input field like so:

```
<input type="text" required minlength="4" name="textfield" value="ab">
```

and I click the submit button, the minlength validation doesn't fire. How can I get it to validate minlength when a value is set?

Comment: why dont you use the placeholder instead like `<input type="text" required minlength="4" name="textfield" placeholder="ab">`

Comment: I am changing the value using javascript. When the validation wasn't working, I figured out that setting a value is what was causing the problem.

Comment: re-check the length before your modification in javascript that you mentioned!